# Acceder a Galeria por medio de apache cordova

Tags: javascript, phonegap, apache-cordova

Estoy desarrollando con apache cordova y necesito crear un boton que me permita acceder a la app de la Galeria. Con android studio lo hacia con el siguiente bloque de codigo

```java
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Hay una forma de hacerlo con Apache Cordova, existe algún simil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando he encontrado el plugin

com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent

instalando con cordova y añadiendo

```
window.plugins.intentShim.startActivityForResult(
            {
                action: window.plugins.intentShim.ACTION_PICK,
                url: "content://com.android.contacts/contacts",
                requestCode: 1
            },
            function(intent)
            {
                if (intent.extras.requestCode == 1)
                {
                    alert('Picked contact: ' + intent.data);
                }
            },
            function()
            {
                alert("StartActivityForResult failure");
            });
```